# Reassembling Python bytecode to the original code?

Tags: python, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

This might be a silly question, but, given the output of, say..

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def myfunc(x):
...     print x ** 2
... 
>>> dis(myfunc)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_POWER        
              7 PRINT_ITEM          
              8 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

..or a `.pyc` file - is it possible to reassembling this into a valid piece of Python source code? I.e where `reassemble(dis(myfunc)) == "def reassembled_function(x):\n    print x ** 2"`

Not for any particular practical reason, I'm just curious if this is possible, or has been attempted..

#### Related

- [Free Python decompiler that is not an online service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211/free-python-decompiler-that-is-not-an-online-service)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/

Comment: This works, but it's quite badly out of date and will have problems with some newer language features (and will probably plain refuse to work on Python 3).

Comment: looks like there is a fork that is still active at https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2  and works for python bytecode from 2.5-2.7