# xdis.code ModuleNotFoundError but the module have already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse-engineering

I am trying to convert `.pyasm` file to `.pyc`  or `.py`file by `xdis`, `xasm` and `uncompyled6`. I have read through this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730802/reassemble-py-file-from-bytecode).

However when i type the command `sudo python /Users/frank/anaconda/envs/py380/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xasm/xasm_cli.py /Users/frank/Desktop/111/flag.pyasm` It returns the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xdis.code'`

However, i have already installed `xdis`,`xasm` and `uncompyle6` with newest version. 
I cannot figure out why. Any suggestions? My environment is MacOS with python3.8.0