# Tried using uncompyle6 and getting an error

Tags: python, decompiler

I've tried using uncompyle6 to decompile my `.pyc` file which I got from my `.exe` file after using pyinstxtractor.py and I'm getting an error:

> ImportError: Unknown magic number 227

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Unknown magic number -> Python-encoded version string.. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730802/reassemble-py-file-from-bytecode/55544456) for more info